# Increase size of LinkedIn share button plugin

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn share plugin (https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) on one of my websites and it works all right. The only problem is that on UHD screens, the share plugin looks tiny. Is there a way to increase the size of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hack I found was to use css to scale the icon using the code below:

```
transform: scale(1.5);
```

This is not perfect and if you have multiple social icons in same row (inline/inline block), they might overlap but you can handle that using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

As I found, tou can't change size of share button, but you can make your custom button as link to https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle ([docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin))